# Regular Expression : Match till the ( character or the end of the buffer) but not the character

Tags: regex, boost, boost-regex

Given the following contents in the smb.conf file. How to remove the **[share_11999]** section using boost(perl version) regex. The problem is the section **[share_11999]** can be at the end of the file.

The following regex almost works except that it removes the "[" of the next section.

**"[[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+?][^\[]+?path = /store/11999.*?(\'|\[)"**

```
[share_11920]
path = /store/11920
writeable = yes
create mask = 0755

[share_11999]
path = /store/11999
writeable = yes
create mask = 0755

[share_12435]
path = /store/12435
writeable = yes
create mask = 0755
```

Basically the problem is to match anything until a character except the character or the end of the buffer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your general question: "How to match anything until a character except the character?"
You can use the following regex:

```
"(.*)(?=word)"
```

This uses the "look ahead / look behind" construct (?=something) to match everything until the certain word and excluding that word.

### Example

```
Test string ==> 'I don't understand the meaning of this word or anything else'
"(.*)(?=word)" applied
'I don't understand the meaning of this'
```

### Demo

http://regex101.com/r/nE4dS6

Comment: And to be able to research this regex construct, the name of the construct is "positive or negative lookahead / lookbehind"

Comment: @MihaiStancu, Thank you. I will include that.

Comment: @sshashank124 Does the bracing of ".*" is necessary?

Comment: @Talespin_Kit, Yes, since it tells the script to get everything until the word.

Comment: @sshashank124 It seems to work without grouping the ".*". Are you assuming that the match will be used(like "\1") later in the program or i am missing something.

Comment: @Talespin_Kit, Potentially, besides, it aids readability and future editing. In the end, choice is yours.